# Does fetch only throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Can I assume that fetch can only **throw** errors of TypeError?

```
const request = async () => {
    let response = null;
    try {
     response = await fetch('https://api.com/values/1');
    } catch (err){
      //is the err here is always of type typeError
    }
    if(!response.ok){
      //bla bla bla 401/403 ...
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}

request();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible for `fetch` to throw an `AbortError`. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Exceptions) for more details